# structure array giving wrong output on sorting

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, structure

1)I have a structure

```
struct node
    {
        char symbol;
        int freq;
        int left, right,root;
        int value;
        short is_sorted;
    };

struct node data[1000];
```

where data[215].freq (frequency) {0,1,2,3,4,5} is obtained by reading following alphabetical symbols(symbol) (abcdef) values from a file "Input.txt" as a sole argument.Now i have to add two minimum frequencies of this array and then position the newly element obtained in the same array such that it will maintain the increasing order of the freq(It  was already sorted array, see we have 0,1,2,3,4,5).

(2)I also have to take care that the two minimum added elements must not participate in sorting and addition again, they must be fixed at their position once if they are already added, but the newly obtained element by addition can participate in addition and sorting again. eg: we add two minimum element 0 and 1, 0+1=1, so "1" is the result obtained by addition, now this "1" must be positioned in data[].freq such that still there should be increasing order. so :

```
data[i].freq = 0 1 1(added here) 2 3 4 5
```

Now we have to again find the minimum two nodes (please read the comment (2) again to understand well) .We cannot add 0 abnd 1 again because they have already participated in in the addition. so this time we will add 1 and 2(this one is at index three, please don't get confused wwith the one at index two). so we get 1+2=3

0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 we again positioned 3 to maintain increasing order. we repeat again: for element at index 4 and 5(because we have already done addition for element at index 0,1 and 2,3) we will get 3+3=6, again position it in data[].freq.

0 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 this time 6 is greater then 4 and 5 so it will appear after 5 to maintain increasing order.

At last we will get `data[dataSize].freq` like this:

```
data[dataSize].freq= [0 1 1 2 3 3  4 5 6 9 15].
```

so the addition held was between index 0,1 and 2,3 and 4,5 and 6, 7 and 8,9 and at last we have 15 which is last one, so here we stops.
*This part i have already done in my code*.
*What help do i need ?*
When i run the code the shows data will look like this:
`Symbol Freq Left Right` (It's actually a huffman tree implementation using only arrays,No malloc and No pointers).

The expected output is this: (when i use qsort() it works fine but i am not using qsort() because of complexity reasons):

```
./extended  Input.txt 
Reading file...
Data is:
0: symbol: a, Freq: 0, Left: -1, Right -1
1: symbol: b, Freq: 1, Left: -1, Right -1
2: symbol: 0, Freq: 1, Left: 0, Right 1
3: symbol: c, Freq: 2, Left: -1, Right -1
4: symbol: d, Freq: 3, Left: -1, Right -1
5: symbol: 5, Freq: 3, Left: 2, Right 3
6: symbol: e, Freq: 4, Left: -1, Right -1
7: symbol: f, Freq: 5, Left: -1, Right -1
8: symbol: 4, Freq: 6, Left: 4, Right 5
9: symbol: 3, Freq: 9, Left: 6, Right 7
10: symbol: 2, Freq: 15, Left: 8, Right 9
d: 00
a: 0100
b: 0101
c: 011
e: 10
f: 11
```

So I have implemented the algorithm i mentioned above and it works well for printing frequency(Freq) **But it don't print the symbols and Left and Right child correctly**, I am trying since long but not able to get the point where i have mistake in my code.(I am sure that tree creation part is correct (which is traverse)tree() function, The problem is some where in the code written in *main() function , moreover i have commented the suspected part*).
Below is my code:

```
nt main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int i,count=0,j,f,s;
struct node data[1000];
int data_size=-1;
if(argc<2)
{
printf("Provide input file..");
return;
}
printf("Reading file...\n");
read_data(argv[1], data, &data_size);
printf("datasize: %d\n", data_size);


  for (i=0; i+1<data_size; i+=2) 
  {
//printf("count1: %d\n", count);
data[data_size].symbol='0'+count;
data[data_size].freq=data[data_size].root =data[i].freq+data[i+1].freq;
data[data_size].left=i;
data[data_size].right=i+1;
data[i].value=0;
data[i+1].value=1;
data[i].is_sorted=1;
data[i+1].is_sorted=1;
data[data_size].value='\0';
data[data_size].is_sorted=0;  

    for (j=data_size-1; j>f+1; j--) 
    {
    if (data[data_size].root >=data[j].freq) 
        {
    //  printf("Inside if loop\n");
        break;
        } 
        else 
        {
        //  printf("else loop\n");  
        data[j+1].freq=data[j].freq;
        data[j+1].symbol=data[j].symbol ;
        data[j+1].left=data[j].left ;
        data[j+1].right=data[j].right ;     
        //data[j+1]=data[j];
        }
        }
        ////////////////
        //printf("data[j+1].sym1: %c\n", data[j+1].symbol );
        data[j+1].freq=data[data_size].root ;
        data[j+1].symbol=data[data_size].symbol ;
        data[j+1].left=data[data_size].left ;
        data[j+1].right=data[data_size].right ;
        count=count_unsorted(data,data_size);
        data_size++;    
        printf("count2: %d\n", count);
}    
printf("Data is:\n");
for(i=0;i<data_size;i++)
{
printf("%d: symbol: %c, Freq: %d, Left: %d, Right %d\n", i,data[i].symbol, data[i].freq, data[i].left, data[i].right);
}
char path[100]={'\0'};
traverse_tree(data, data_size-1,path);
return 0;
}
```

Bu the output of my code is:

```
  Reading file...
    0: symbol: a, Freq: 0, Left: -1, Right -1
    1: symbol: b, Freq: 1, Left: -1, Right -1
    2: symbol: f, Freq: 1, Left: -1, Right -1
    3: symbol: c, Freq: 2, Left: -1, Right -1
    4: symbol: d, Freq: 3, Left: -1, Right -1
    5: symbol: f, Freq: 3, Left: -1, Right -1
    6: symbol: e, Freq: 4, Left: -1, Right -1
    7: symbol: f, Freq: 5, Left: -1, Right -1
    8: symbol: 2, Freq: 6, Left: 4, Right 5
    9: symbol: 3, Freq: 9, Left: 6, Right 7
    10: symbol: 4, Freq: 15, Left: 8, Right 9
    f: 11
    e: 10
    f: 01
    d: 00
    hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop
```

When i try to do :
printf("data[j].sym: %c\n", data[data_size].symbol );insde the commented part (which is the most suspected part where i assin the values to element and symbols)" then i have very strange value of symbol which is `"data[j].sym: f data[j].sym: f data[j].sym: 2 data[j].sym: 3 data[j].sym: 4 "` I don't know why it has "f" at first two places , there should be "`0 1 2 3 4`" not "`f f 2 3 4` "

Comment: Have you run this code in a debugger, and placed break points in the problem region of code?

Comment: @ryyker Thaks for the reply. I am using notepad++, there is nothing to debug in notepad++. but i am sure that the problem is in the part where i have writen "/Below is the most suspected part for wrong output /////" , I am trying to fix it since morning and now it's night here.Still not able to do, Please help me

Comment: If your code compiles but gives wrong results, there **is** something to debug. Even if it's `printf` debug. You can also at least run it through `gdb` if you work on nix-like system.

Comment: @luk32 Yes i tried to check the output using"printf" (even you can see the commented printf),But the values are very strange, I am not able to understand why it gives such a strance value.For example, If i un-comment " printf("data[j].sym2: %c\n", data[data_size].symbol );" then i have very strange value of symbol which is "data[j].sym2: f
data[j].sym2: f
data[j].sym2: 2
data[j].sym2: 3
data[j].sym2: 4
" I don't know why it has "f" at first two places , there should be "0 1 2 3 4" not "f f 2 3 4 "

Comment: @ryyker do you know what is the problem in my code? i am still not able to solve it.

Comment: @harper , Have you been able to predict the mistake in the code ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. It looks like a design problem. You had to post too much code to show your problem. You might have tried to provide a SSCCE. But it's only a SCCE w/o the required data input. You have been suggested to use a debugger. I am reluctant to follow the advise you got to fix your code.

Comment: @harper I have posted my full code here. I am really not able to solve it since long time. That's why i prefered to put on stackover flow(some one told me that there i can get it solved by senior experts)

Comment: SO will not do your work. Try http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @harperThanks for the suggestion.I have done it using other way. below is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at last,I have just done it myself:Here i put code for someone if getsimilar type of problem in future:

```
void sort_array(struct node *data, int length)
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<length-1 && data[i].freq<=data[length-1].freq;i++); //This loop breaks when it gets the desired position, So complexity is about n-1 for total n elements.
for(j=length-1;j>i;j--)
{
struct node temp;
temp.symbol=data[j].symbol;
temp.freq=data[j].freq;
temp.left=data[j].left;
temp.right=data[j].right;
temp.value=data[j].value;

data[j].symbol=data[j-1].symbol;
data[j].freq=data[j-1].freq;
data[j].left=data[j-1].left;
data[j].right=data[j-1].right;
data[j].value=data[j-1].value;

data[j-1].symbol=temp.symbol;
data[j-1].freq=temp.freq;
data[j-1].left=temp.left;
data[j-1].right=temp.right;
data[j-1].value=temp.value;
}
}
```